# How can I crop the image to specific width and height to img src in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, image, thumbnails

In my WordPress theme to get recent post images, the code is

```
$gallery = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'property_gallery', true);
$images = explode("~~~", $gallery);
<img src="' . esc_url($images[1]) . '" alt="' . esc_attr($title) . '" />
```

The code displays the the recent property images but the problem is that the image I get is in full resolution.

I want to crop the image to 200x200 or 100x100.

You can see the recently listed properties here in full resolution image, which is causing page loading problem.
http://dxboffplan.com/developers/

Answer (score 1):

You simply define the thumbnail size that you require in the functions.php of your theme.

```
// create square image size 
add_image_size( 'square-thumb', 300, 300, true );

add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'my_custom_sizes' );
function my_custom_sizes( $sizes ) {
    return array_merge( $sizes, array(
        'square-thumb' => __( 'Square Thumb' ),
    ) );
}
```

Change the size from 300 to whatever value you require.

It's a good idea to regenerate thumnbnails afterward, there are a few plugins that can help: https://en-za.wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should add the image size in functions.php of your desired one. To do so,

```
// create square image size 
add_image_size( 'recent-images', 200, 200, true ); //true means hard crop
```

This will crop the new image size to 200 * 200 for new upload images.

**Important:** The size will not be generated from already uploaded images rather it will generate for new upload images only.

To generate size for already uploaded images you have to get plugins which can be found in the plugin directory.

Now, after addding the image size, you just need to have some changes to the your code.

```
$gallery = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'property_gallery', true);
$images = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $gallery, 'recent-images' );
<img src="<?php echo $images[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($title); ?>" />  //updated this line only
```

**UPDATED:** The last line with img tag was not properly syntax with PHP. I have updated the code which should work fine. I have tested again in my server it is working.

Hope this work.

Thank You

Comment: wp_get_attachment_image_src is not getting img, actually the recent post image is not featured image of a post, it is a custom post field input where i upload gallery images to the post.

Comment: @SajjadAhmad see the updated answer above. I have made a syntax error in last ine of the code hope you will get the result now. Thank YOU

Comment: thank you your time and effort but unfortunately, still img src is empty. but i got it different way.
now i am using featured img my code is this:

$imgUrl =  wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'thumbnail' );

<img src="<?php echo $imgUrl[0]; ?>" alt=" <?php echo esc_html($post->post_title) ; ?> ">